# The Horizontal Scroll bar is not being placed in the location that i want

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple python GUI Application. I added the vertical scrollbar properly and it is functioning well, but now that I'm trying to add a horizontal scroll bar, it is functioning but its position is all messed up,
I have tried the pack geometry manager, it's just not giving me the desired output, I want the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the window inside the canvas.

This is the Code section that I'm having trouble with...

```
        self.frame_2 = Frame(self, bg='skyblue',)
        self.frame_2.place(x=0, y=150)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame_2, bg='orange', height=200, width=300,)
        self.canvas.pack(side='left',expand=True,fill=BOTH)

        self.win_in_can = Frame(self.canvas, bg='orange')

        self.myscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame_2,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.myscrollbar_h = Scrollbar(self.frame_2, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar_h.set, yscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set)

        self.myscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.myscrollbar_h.pack(side='left',fill='x')

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.win_in_can, anchor='nw')
        self.win_in_can.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Comment: Try `self.myscrollbar_h.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')` ?

Comment: i tried 'bottom' too, its not working

Comment: Tried `grid()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pack canvas only after packing scroll bars (both horizontal and vertical)

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.frame_2 = Frame(self, bg='skyblue',)
    self.frame_2.place(x=0, y=150)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame_2, bg='orange', height=200, width=300,)
    
    self.win_in_can = Frame(self.canvas, bg='orange')

    self.myscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame_2,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.myscrollbar_h = Scrollbar(self.frame_2, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
    self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar_h.set, yscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set)
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.win_in_can, anchor='nw')
    self.win_in_can.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
    self.myscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
    self.myscrollbar_h.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill='x')
    self.canvas.pack(side='left',expand=True,fill=BOTH)
    for i in range(100):
        Button(self.win_in_can,text=str(i)).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly telling `pack` to place the scrollbar on the left. If you want it below the canvas, use `side='bottom'`. You also need to pack it before the canvas.

I find that layout is much easier to manage when you group your layout code in a single blog, arranged in groups.

```
self.myscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
self.myscrollbar_h.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')
self.canvas.pack(side='left',expand=True,fill=BOTH)
```